# MIPS -- Tracing this code

Tags: mips

I was given the code example below.

The code counts/prints down to 0 from whatever number is in `$a0` (which is being passed as an argument). I can following everything except what is being done with `$ra`.  That part is confusing me.

I know when we use `jal` that `$ra` keeps track of the return address (so the program knows where to go back to).  Tracing through the code though at first `$ra` is saved on the stack and is set to where we will return to once the function is done executing. However, each time `printnums` is called again doesn't that create a new `$ra` value?  That value would then be saved in memory.  That would mean when we `jr` at the end it would jump to the last value of `$ra` that was saved (which points to the `ret:` after the `jal printnums`)?

Or is it that each time `$ra` is saved that 4 additional bytes are being reserved in memory instead of overwriting the same 4 bytes over and over?  If that were the case, when we are deallocating space on the stack we are 'popping' each `$ra` until we hit the first one that was saved and return to the correct spot out of the function.  Is that correct?

I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. Thanks for the help.

```
printnums:              # $a0 has value
addi $sp, $sp, -4         # reserve room for return address
sw $ra, ($sp)             # save return address
beq $a0, $0, ret          # check ending condition
addi $v0, $0, 1           # set command to print int
syscall                 # print value in $a0
addi $a0, $a0, -1         # decrement value
jal printnums           # call printnums again
ret:
lw $ra, ($sp)             # restore $ra
addi $sp, $sp, 4          # deallocate space on stack
jr  $ra              # return
```

Comment: This is an example of an optimization called Tail Call Elimination http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recursive function. During each iteration of the function, the stack is increased by 4 bytes to hold a return address, and a number is printed.

Imagine we have this piece of code calling printnums:

```
caller:
    li  $a0 4
    jal printnums
```

Here's what the stack would look like after each call (which all have different values of `$a0`)

```
      ╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
  $a0:║   4    ║   3    ║   2    ║ 1      ║
      ╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
stack:║ caller ║ caller ║ caller ║ caller ║
      ║        ║ ret    ║ ret    ║ ret    ║
      ║        ║        ║ ret    ║ ret    ║
      ║        ║        ║        ║ ret    ║
      ╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

When `$a0` reaches the value of 0, the stack begins to *unwind* with each value being popped off one by one as each invocation of `printnums` begins to return. The most recent four invocations will restore `$ra` from the stack and return to `ret`, but the last will pop off the return value `caller` and return to the caller of `printnums` thus operating as intended.